# Is there a cap on the number of entry in a ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, eclipse, dictionary

I am working to read a file of about 2 million entries. Not all are valid lines, but that's the cap. I am using a Map to store key value pairings from the file. I however find that the last term is at line 1932513. I am coding with eclipse, in Java, and went over to bump up the Xmx parameters in the eclipse.ini. This did not solve the problem. Here is the code I am working with:

```
BufferedReader bufferedRead = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
        String data;
        try {
            while((data = bufferedRead.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] meterReadings = data.split(";");
                if("Date".equals(meterReadings[0])) continue;
/*
 *  Creating the key object using concatenation of date-time        
 */
                if(newApp.isEmpty(meterReadings)) continue;
                List<Object> valueList = new ArrayList<Object>();
                String[] subDate = meterReadings[0].split("/");
                StringBuffer dateTime = new StringBuffer();
                for(String s : subDate) {
                    dateTime.append(s + ":");
                }

                dateTime.append(meterReadings[1]);
                for(int i=2; i < meterReadings.length -1; ++i) {            
                    valueList.add(meterReadings[i]);
                }
                newApp.textMap.put(dateTime.toString(), valueList);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Unable to read from file: ", App.DATA_DIR + App.FILENAME);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
/*
 *  Checking to see if Map has been created      
 */
        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        Set<String> newSet = newApp.textMap.keySet();
        Object[] setArray = newSet.toArray();
        System.out.println("The last term's key is : " + (String) setArray[setArray.length - 1]);
        System.out.println(newApp.textMap.size());
        log.info("The size of the reading is : ", newApp.textMap.size());
        System.out.println("*****************************************");

    }
```

Comment: You don't want to store all this in RAM. Instead, use a proper cache library that can flush to disk like EhCache or Infinispan.

Comment: If you search you can find the source for ConcurrentHashMap somewhere on the web.  Examine it and find out what they use for the main storage facility -- whether a single array or multiple linked ones or whatever.  Then be aware that most JVMs place a limit on the size of a single array of anywhere from 16MB to 2GB, and an entry in an array of references is usually 8 bytes, so the array is limited from between 2M and 256M entries.  (Though how the algorithm handles "overflows" is another twist on things.)  (And, of course, the overall heap has a limit.)

Comment: Thanks Luiggi. I eventually do not intend to. The end goal is to write a Yarn application,  so this is incremental. I felt i could deal with that inefficiency as i have a 12gb pc i'm working with. Just want to test out my solution locally before i go on to write it to run on a hadoop cluster. I will look into cache but pressed for time. Do you see the RAM as the reason here ?

Comment: Perform tests on your implementation and discover if RAM is really the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks, Luigi. Would check that out.

Comment: 1: -Xmx and other JVM settings in eclipse.ini apply to the JVM that runs Eclipse; settings for the JVM that runs your app are in the Run/Debug Configuration entry (or entries) you use for your app, and if not set default to those of the JRE or other Execution Environment you use. 2: the keys and entries in a HashMap are in what is colloquially called "random" order; it isn't truly random, but it is opaque, not fixed and not either chronological or by value, so the array[length-1] entry you show is NOT the one inserted last NOR the one with the highest value.

Comment: Thanks for pointing these out dave_thompson_085